# Android Media recorder output file size 0KB

Tags: android, android-camera, android-file, android-fileprovider

I am recording video with MediaRecorder, which is working fine on most devices. But on few devices like MI A2, Samsung J2,J7 etc, regardless os OS version, output recording file size is 0KB. I have turned requestLegacyExternalStorage mode on in menifest. Also I have tried creating and saving files to check if there is any issue with file generation, but there isn't. I have added most of the code below.

Media file generation code:

```
public File getOutputMediaFile() {

        File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES), "Liveliness");


        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("Liveliness", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File videoFile;
        videoFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +
                "REC_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");



        return videoFile;
    }
```

Camera Prepare code.

```
 mCamera = cameraSource.getCameraInstance();
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        // Step 1: Unlock and set camera to MediaRecorder
        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a format
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);

        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);

        CamcorderProfile cpHigh = CamcorderProfile.get(cameraSource.getRequestedCameraId(), CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
        // Set the video encoding bit rate this changes for the high, low.
        // medium quality devices
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(cpHigh.videoBitRate);

        //Set the video frame rate
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(cpHigh.videoFrameRate);

        // Step 4: Set output file
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile());
        }else{
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputMediaFile().getPath());

        }

        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            mediaRecorder.setInputSurface(MediaCodec.createPersistentInputSurface());
        }

mediaRecorder.prepare();
```

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution please??